# Cannot connect to Bluetooth devices

Tags: networking, usb, 22.04, bluetooth

it seems that suddenly my ubuntu machine denies connecting to bluetooth devices. I don't know if it was after or before an update (becuase I don't test Bluetooth often) but trying to connect to a bluetooth device I get the following behaviour. Connecting to my mobile phone has a bit more strange behaviour. First it connects, it almost immediately dissconnects and then the same behaviour as the image attached. I restarting bluetooth service, `apt install bluez` but nothing.

Any help would be great!

ubuntu version is 22.04 and laptop is dell xps13 9370.
Bluetooth device is

```bash
sudo lshw | grep -i -A 10 -B 10 blue

*-usb:2
                   description: Bluetooth wireless interface
                   manufacturer: Foxconn / Hon Hai
                   physical id: 7
                   bus info: usb@1:7
                   version: 0.01
                   capabilities: bluetooth usb-1.10
                   configuration: driver=btusb maxpower=100mA speed=12Mbit/s
```

kernel version is `5.19.0-41-generic`

[image]